# Negative probability meaning

Tags: probability, matrices, markov-chains

I have a project that uses Continuous Time Markov Chain as the method to solve the problem. As you know, a CTMC rate transition matrix ($Q$) row's sum has to be zero. It means the if there are $2$ states and probability from state $1$ jump to state  $2$ is $a$, then the probability the state remain in state $1$ is $-a$.

My question is, what is the negative probability meaning? I mean, we know that based on probability theory, probability range is just $0$ to $1$.

Can anyone explain it? Thank you.

Comment: I am very sure that the rows have to add to one, since the probability of switching plus the probability of staying must add to one.

Comment: A probability cannot be negative.

Comment: You are confusing  probability transition matrices (mostly in discrete time, nonnegative entries, rows sum to $1$) with probability rate matrices (only in continuous time, nonnegative offdiagonal entries, rows sum to $0$). A more careful look at your textbook might prove useful.

Comment: Elements of the $Q$-matrix are 'instantaneous' rates, and its elements $q_{ij}$ are defined in such a way that rows of $Q$ sum to $0.$